# ASP.NET Detecting Page Refesh in Page_Init

Tags: asp.net, refresh

I need to detect when a user refreshing the page in the Page_Init event to stop them from executing the same code twice. What's the way to do this in ASP.NET

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's [an article](http://aspalliance.com/687_Preventing_Duplicate_Record_Insertion_on_Page_Refresh.4) that talks about some different ways of dealing with this problem, though I'm not sure it matches 100% with your situation.

Comment: +1 there are various solutions in the article that should in one way or another address most any issue in this problem class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [`Page.IsPostBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) property:

> Gets a value indicating whether the
>   page is being loaded in response to a
>   client postback, or if it is being
>   loaded and accessed for the first
>   time.

Comment: I believe he's talking about a page refresh (e.g., press F5), not a postback.

Comment: Page.IsPostBack doesn't seem to work. It's always false. The post back isn't coming from a control, its if you refresh your browser

Comment: You probably shouldn't be doing anything non-repeatable on a GET request anyway - it shouldn't have any side effects, and should potentially be able to be cached - you should be using a POST of some kind to perform your non-repeatable actions, and then you would be able to check your IsPostBack correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can set cookie with short expiration time after first request on your site. Then you can simply check it and enlarge the cookie expiration.